# Powershell Select-Object Property multiple comparisons same property

Tags: powershell, csv, filter, properties, select-object

I am using Select-Object to filter a CSV to get the necessary columns.
When I use this: `$Filter = $Csv | Select-Object ($Csv[0].PSObject.Properties.Name -like "*Results*"` it filters all columns and displays everything containing results, this works fine. But how do I get it to keep my first column where the header is "Sample" as well as keeping the results? I have tried without success:

```
$Filter = $Csv | Select-Object ($Csv[0].PSObject.Properties.Name -like "*Results*" -and $Csv[0].PSObject.Properties.Name -like "Sample")
```

I understand you can add multiple properties comma separated but I am looking for the same property but with multiple matching parameters.

The output would include a column that have header name "Sample" and columns that would contain the word "Results". They both work individually in the first line of code provided, but how do i make it work together with both matching strings?

Edit: Expected output added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass multiple property (column) names to the (possibly positionally implied) `-Property` parameter of the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) cmdlet using an expression (`(...)`), you must pass a *flat array*.

To that end, use `+` for concatenation, making sure that (at least) the LHS is an array.

The following places the `Sample` property first, using `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) to wrap it in an array:

```
$Csv |
  Select-Object (@('Sample') + ($Csv[0].PSObject.Properties.Name -like "*Results*"))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for and very concise.  The array wrapping is all new to me.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Mufacka; my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

`Select-Object`'s `-Property` parameter takes an *array* of property names (see documentation at [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2)).

Your individual expressions (`$Csv[0].PSObject.Properties.Name -like "*Results*"` and `$Csv[0].PSObject.Properties.Name -like "Sample"`) each individually return an array of matching columns as expected, but when you `-and` them together it becomes a boolean expression that returns `$true` or `$false` so your `Select-Object` becomes the equivalent of:

```bash
$Filter = $Csv | Select-Object -Property @( $true )
```

To demonstrate this, we'll use some sample data:

```bash
$csv = @"
Sample, Sample2, Something Else, A1Results, ResultsZ2
aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee
"@

$data = $csv | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

and then see what your individual expressions return:

```bash
PS> ($data[0].PSObject.Properties.Name -like "*Results*")
A1Results
ResultsZ2

PS> ($data[0].PSObject.Properties.Name -like "Sample")
Sample
```

and now we'll try your combined expression:

```bash
PS> ($data[0].PSObject.Properties.Name -like "*Results*") -and ($data[0].PSObject.Properties.Name -like "Sample")
True
```

If you want to generate the list of all matching columns you'll need to combine the two separate lists in a different way - you can add them together and PowerShell will return a new array that contains the two separate arrays concatenated:

```bash
PS> ($data[0].PSObject.Properties.Name -like "*Results*") + ($data[0].PSObject.Properties.Name -like "Sample")
A1Results
ResultsZ2
Sample
```

and then if you plug that back into your original code you get this:

```bash
PS> $data | Select-Object ( ($data[0].PSObject.Properties.Name -like "*Results*") + ($data[0].PSObject.Properties.Name -like "Sample") )

A1Results ResultsZ2 Sample
--------- --------- ------
ddd       eee       aaa
```

**Cheeky Update**

@mklement0 notes in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73284343/3156906) that the left-hand side of the + needs to be an array in order for the addition operator to trigger array concatenation. You can ensure this by coercing the result of the individual expressions into arrays using the [Array Subexpression Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#array-subexpression-operator--) like this:

```bash
PS> $data | Select-Object ( @($data[0].PSObject.Properties.Name -like "*Results*") + @($data[0].PSObject.Properties.Name -like "Sample") )
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. Definitely learned a lot of valuable things from it.